# Sorting a ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, dataframe, boxplot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

I have the following data frame (`df`) in R that I wish to create a box plot for:

```
    Entity  Mean    Min Q1      Med     Q3      Max
1   ABCD    88.65   0   75.0    100.0   100.0   100
2   BAAF    88.73   0   91.0    100.0   100.0   100
3   BCC4    70.26   0   20.0    100.0   100.0   100
4   C9FE    77.98   0   66.0    86.0    100.0   100
5   D3AA    71.97   0   51.0    82.0    100.0   100
```

The code I use is as follows:

```
Lplot <- ggplot(df, aes(Entity, ymin=Min, lower=Q1, middle=Med, upper=Q3, ymax=Max,
         fill=Mean))
mth <- theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
bplot <- geom_boxplot(stat="identity")
sfg <- scale_fill_gradient("Mean", low="green", high="red")

Lplot + mth + sfg + bplot
```

This graphs the data frame with `Entity` on the x-axis and the appropriate quantiles on the y-axis. However, I would like to sort the plots by `Mean`.
I can achieve this effect by replacing `aes(Entity,...` with `aes(factor(Mean),...` but then the mean values appear on the x-axis when I still want the `Entity` names there.

Essentially what I am after is a boxplot sorted by `Mean` but labelled by `Entity`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

`Entity` needs to be a factor with levels sorted in the right order:

```
df$Entity <- factor(df$Entity, levels = df$Entity[rank(df$Mean)])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was after. However, it doesn't work with duplicate Mean values, is there a way of automatically handling (without removing) duplicates?